# How do I make a pile of fibers?

Tags: particles, hair

I need to make a pile of hair-like fibers. My instinct is to create a fiber-shaped particle emitter, let the particles fall onto a surface and then convert them to mesh. Am I on the right track? Thanks for your time.

Reference pictures:
[image: Hand holding a small pile of nylon fibers]

[image]

Comment: maybe show a reference picture of what it is supposed to look like.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add reference images that might help us understand what you are looking forn and also add information on what you have tried so far. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))

Comment: Reference picture was added.